# How to forward (not redirect) requests in PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, request, forward

I am working on a simple PHP site that involves needing to be able to forward a request made by the user to another page (note that I said *forward*, and not *redirect*). I am aware of how to redirect by manipulating the `header` variable, but I do not wish to do this, as explained below.

I am trying to write a very simple MVC-patterned mailing list app in PHP, drawing from my knowledge of the same in JSP. One of the things that I appreciated about JSP was that you could both **forward** or **redirect** a request. For my purposes, I need *forward* as I wish to keep the request parameters (whereas *redirect* will drop them).

Here is a description of what I wish to accomplish:

- Retrieve input from a form (*ie. /add.php*)
- Process the input in the page called by the form's action (*ie. /process.php*) and add a success message to the request object
- Forward to another page (*ie. /display.php*) to display the success message in the request object

The only way I am aware of passing the request message to display is to add it to the request object and then access it from the forwarded page. However, the only way I have had success in transitioning to another page is through using the `header` method, which drops the request object (from what I can tell). I want to find a way to *forward* the request (object) to the new page, so that I can access the request variables from the new page.

Is there actually anyway to do this in PHP? Java's `getRequestDispatcher.forward()` is so nice, but I can't find an equivalent through searching. I've tried several similar questions, including the following, but I've never actually found one where both the question and the answer were what I wanted. Most of the answers seem to have something to do with cURL, but I don't want to actually retrieve a file, but simply forward a request in order to access the request object from another page.

[Does PHP have an equivalent of Java's getRequestDispatcher.forward()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433774/does-php-have-an-equivalent-of-javas-requestdispatcher-forward)

Let me know if I should include anything else?

Comment: Are you using any framework or clean PHP?

Comment: @michaJlS I am using clean PHP, hoping to create my own MVC-like structure.

Comment: You can save a lot of time by using one;) e.g. for not having to implement own forward.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but thought that this would be a good experience, as I'm trying to stay rather simple (although just wanting PHP forwarding may already disqualify that :) ).

Comment: @KendallRoth, not as much PHP forwarding as it is HTTP.

Comment: There are nice smooth PHP micro frameworks, which will allow you to stay simple, and probably by reading their code you can learn more than by writing own in that case. Look at Lumen or Silex.

Comment: At one point I had thought about using Lavavel, but decided I should keep learning basic PHP before that, which kind of steered me away from frameworks. I think I'll at least look at them, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with include. Before submitting the form just use, as inclusion, in main page:

```
include ("add.php"); - where the input forms are
```

after processing the information, include the display.php in the same way; using this, display.php will use same parameters from header, because is included in the same main page.

briefly: add.php, process.php and display.php will be modules for the mother page, but loaded in different state of form processing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This seems to me the only intelligent way to offer MVC control of the page view based on the flow of control. You could make a single page application in this way, in which the only navigable page would contain a decision tree of such includes.

Comment: In fact the more I am looking at PHP, that seems the only intelligent way to put together a PHP website.

Answer (score 0):

use curl with different method get,post. it will sent a request and also get back the response.

Answer (score 0):

The most common method I see of passing messages to the end user from page to page is called session flashing.

This is when you store a variable temporarily in the session until it is read.

Assuming you already have sessions in use:

On process.php:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = 'Your data has been saved!';
```

On display.php:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```

You could also store the entire Request object in the session.

Comment: Interesting concept, I've never thought/heard of that before (that I can remember). I might just have to try this sometime!

Answer (score 0):

So if I am aware, PHP provides just basic set of tools in this case. And there is nothing like "forward" in HTTP originally. It is just frameworks' abstraction/idea. There are two ways to achieve that: copying all params from request and doing new real HTTP request (with redirect) or internal forward: so framework would create fake request and call another controller and action without issuing  a new physical HTTP request.